# How do I update a firebird timestamp field to remove milliseconds part?

Tags: timestamp, firebird

Is there a simple update statement I can execute to update a timestamp field in a firebird database to remove millisecond part.

so current value is:        9-DEC-2013 8:55:57.3560
i want to update it to be:  9-DEC-2013 8:55:57.0000

I need a generic update statement that calculates the new timestamp based upon the old timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard function in Firebird to do this. However with help of the built-in functions [`EXTRACT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-extract) and [`DATEADD`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-dateadd) you will be able to construct this.

```sql
DATEADD(-1 * EXTRACT(MILLISECOND FROM theTimestamp) MILLISECOND TO theTimestamp)
```

The only problem with this solution is that it doesn't work correctly if your timestamps have a 100 microsecond part, as the documentation of `DATEADD` states:

> `<amount>`    ::=  an integer expression (negative to subtract)

And the 100 microsecond part is a decimal fraction of the amount, and can't be changed this way. I have filed ticket [CORE-4457](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-4457) to have this changed, and starting with Firebird 3, `DATEADD(... MILLISECOND TO ...)` will now accept a fractional value.

However as a lot of client libraries only use or support millisecond precision this probably will not affect you (even the built-in `CURRENT_TIME` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` are limited to millisecond precision).

Answer (score 1):

You can play with [EXTRACT()](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-extract) internal function.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
v_TimeIn = cast(extract(Hour from v_TimeIn)||':'||
    extract(minute from v_TimeIn) as Time);
```